# How to prevent execution of a PHP file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I want to prevent the running of `x.php` but I can't see how to do it in cPanel. I also can't see how to do it the `.htaccess`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the file if you don't want people to run it?

Comment: i want to stop run without delete or rename file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to modify the file with a run key that only you know.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['runkey']) || ($_GET['runkey'] != my-secret-value)) {
   die("You do not have permission to run this script");
}
```

Then when *you* wanted to run the script, you'd call it with

https://my-site.com/my_script.php?runkey=my-secret-value

Comment: error syntax : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file's permissions so it is not executable. You can do this from either cPanel, FTP (right-click the file and change permissions) or from the command line (chmod).

Comment: I'm not sure what this means.